# Rendering environment variables in an Ansible shell command

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm trying to run a shell command on a remote host using Ansible, and this command must also include a *local* environment variable.

While the variable is correctly set, the output is not the one I'd expect and I don't understand why.

This is a sample playbook that I prepared for this case:

```yaml
---
- name: "Ansible local variable in shell command"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    variable: "{{ lookup('env', 'VARIABLE') }}"
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: "Prints the local variable"
    shell: "echo {{ vars.variable }}"
    register: "output"
  - debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

If running `VARIABLE=random ansible-playbook playbook.yml` I would expect it to print `random`, what I get instead is this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo {{ lookup('env', 'VARIABLE') }}", "delta": "0:00:00.004725", "end": "2023-02-17 21:56:21.282225", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2023-02-17 21:56:21.277500", "stderr": "/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('\n/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `echo {{ lookup('env', 'VARIABLE') }}'", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('", "/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `echo {{ lookup('env', 'VARIABLE') }}'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

The most relevant part is the content of `stderr`, where we can see this one:

```
"/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('\n/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `echo {{ lookup('env', 'VARIABLE') }}'
```

From my understanding, this means that `vars.variable` has been considered as a plain string instead of being rendered with the result of the `lookup` function.

But why does this happen? What am I missing on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use `vars.variable` (which contains the raw Jinja2 string as seen in your error message) but simply `variable` as demonstrated in the following fixed example:

```yaml
---
- name: "Ansible local variable in shell command"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    variable: "{{ lookup('env', 'VARIABLE') }}"
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: "Prints the local variable"
    #shell: "echo {{ vars.variable }}"
    shell: "echo {{ variable }}"
    register: "output"
  - debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

works fine for me:

```bash
$ VARIABLE="Hello, world" ansible-playbook playbook2.yml
PLAY [Ansible local variable in shell command] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Prints the local variable] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": [
        "Hello, world"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but why using `vars.variable` doesn't? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: What **is** documented is using `variable`: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html So just use what is supposed to.